# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

trying to install or uninstall any kind of software de output always is the same code `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Here trying to install java 8

1. Add the PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   ```
2. Update and install the installer script:

   ```
   sudo apt update; sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
   ```
3. Check the Java version:

   ```
   javac -version
   ```
4. Set Java environment variables:

   ```
   sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
   ```

On the step 2

[image]

Comment: That's just a list of the truncated list of affected packages, part of the summary. We need the entire, complete output.

Comment: Is there a reason you are posting images of text instead of simply copy-and-pasting the text? You are more likely to get better help without the unnecessary link.